# how to save and fetch at the same time in coredata swift3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my current project I am saving datas like(image attributes) into coredata but while fetching instantly it's not giving me the exact numbers of data.Most of the time giving less number of data than what I saved.But in log it's showing that all datas are successfully saved.My questing is before fetching I can see the log so there is no question of that the datas are not saved properly.Please help me to get out of this problem.

```
func saveImageDetails(aImage: UIImage?, imageUrl: String!, phAsset: PHAsset!, objectType: String, objectId: String, objectName:String,location: String?){

        if let newImage = aImage {

            let   date  = HelpherMethod.sharedInstance().toLocalTime(Date())
            let resource = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: phAsset!).first
            let fileName = resource?.originalFilename
            var  imageName : String?
            let timestamp = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
            print(String(format:"%.0f",timestamp!))
            let currentTimeStamp = String(format:"%.0f",timestamp!)
            imageName = String(format:"%@_%@",AuthService.instance.userName,currentTimeStamp)

            let mImage = self.objectWithTypePredicate(aType: "Image", predicate: NSPredicate(format:"(imageName == %@)",imageName!), canCreate: true)

            mImage?.setValue(fileName, forKey: "fileName")
            mImage?.setValue(date, forKey: "dateTime")
            mImage?.setValue(objectId, forKey: "objectId")
            mImage?.setValue(objectType, forKey: "objectType")
            mImage?.setValue(objectName, forKey: "objectName")
            mImage?.setValue(newImage, forKey: "image")
            mImage?.setValue(imageName, forKey: "imageName")
            mImage?.setValue(imageUrl, forKey: "imageUrl")
            if let loc = location {
                mImage?.setValue(loc, forKey: "location")
            }
            mImage?.setValue("progress", forKey: "status") //Status failed for not uploaded // progress for processing// success for sync// at the initial level all status are set to progress
            do {
                try mImage?.managedObjectContext?.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }
        }
   }


//fethcing from coredata

func fetchRecordsWithClassName(entityName: String , sortingKey: String , isAscending: Bool , predicate: NSPredicate? , isAllrecord: Bool ) -> Array<Any>{


         let   managedContext = PLMCoreDataInstance.managedObjectContext
        // Initialize Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest  =  NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>() as NSFetchRequest
        //create entity description
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: managedContext!)
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortingKey, ascending: isAscending)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        // optional chaining
        if let newPredicate = predicate {
            fetchRequest.predicate = newPredicate
        }
        //Configure fetch Request
        fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
        do {
            if let results = try? managedContext?.fetch(fetchRequest)  {
                return results!
            }
        }
        return []
    }
```

Comment: Do a save before you fetch . Are you doing it in code after you write ?

Comment: After writing into coredata I am just fetching

Comment: By writing I mean do you save your context ?

Comment: Please do check my code .Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Try calling `fetchRecordsWithClassName` after some delay of 0.6 s and check

Comment: Are you using different managed object contexts from different threads?  Where does your “save” context come from.

Comment: I have tried with different managed object contexts from different threads but no luck.

Comment: the situation is you can select multiple images from collection view on click so when i click one by one it's working fine but while selecting randomly and fast then not giving the exact saved images count from DB .Please help me it's really urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it worked by using the below code and using parent-child context like creating private `managedObjectContext` in a background thread.

```
func saveImageDetailsFromArray(dictionary : Dictionary<String, Any>,descriptiondictionary : Dictionary<String, Any>?, selectedImages: Array<PHAsset>, objectType: String, objectId: String, objectName:String,location: String?,completionHandler :@escaping PLMCoreDataCompletionHandler){

    let moc = self.managedObjectContext //Our primary context on the main queue
    let privateMOC = self.backgroundContext

    for phAsset in selectedImages{

        privateMOC?.perform {

            let index = selectedImages.index(of: phAsset)
            let   date  = HelpherMethod.sharedInstance().toLocalTime(Date())
            let timestamp = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
            print(String(format:"%f",timestamp!))
            let currentTimeStamp = String(format:"%f",timestamp!)
            var  imageName : String?
            imageName = String(format:"%@_%@",AuthService.instance.userName,currentTimeStamp)
            let  newImage = dictionary[phAsset.localIdentifier]
            let resource = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: phAsset).first
            let fileName = resource?.originalFilename
            let userName = AuthService.instance.userName
            let mImage = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Image", into: privateMOC!) as! Image

            mImage.setValue(fileName, forKey: "fileName")
            mImage.setValue(date, forKey: "dateTime")
            mImage.setValue(objectId, forKey: "objectId")
            mImage.setValue(objectType, forKey: "objectType")
            mImage.setValue(objectName, forKey: "objectName")
            mImage.setValue(newImage, forKey: "image")
            mImage.setValue(imageName, forKey: "imageName")
            mImage.setValue(phAsset.localIdentifier, forKey: "imageUrl")
            mImage.setValue(userName, forKey: "userName")
            mImage.setValue("progress", forKey: "status")

            if let loc = location {
                mImage.setValue(loc, forKey: "location")
            }
            if let dict  = descriptiondictionary{
                if let description = dict[phAsset.localIdentifier] {
                    mImage.setValue(description, forKey: "comment")
                }
            }

            do {
                try privateMOC?.save()
                moc.performAndWait {
                    do {
                        try moc.save()
                        print("###########save context: \(String(describing: mImage))")
                        print("###########imageName: \(String(describing: imageName)))")

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if(index == selectedImages.count - 1){
                                print("###########index: \(String(describing: index)))")
                                completionHandler(true)
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

VIEWCONTROLLER--1:
====================>

```
import UIKit

import CoreData



class ViewController-1: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource

{

    @IBOutlet var table_view: UITableView!

    var my_data_array = NSMutableArray()

    var data_array = NSMutableArray()

    var data_fet:[NSManagedObject] = []



    override func viewDidLoad()

    {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)

    {

        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate



        let context_view = app.persistentContainer.viewContext



        let fetch_data = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Student_detail")

        do

        {

//            



            data_array = try context_view.fetch(fetch_data as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! NSMutableArray

            print("this is array",data_array)

        }

        catch let error as NSError

        {

            print(error)

        }

        table_view.reloadData()

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int

    {

        return 1

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

    {

        return data_array.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

    {

        let t_cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_data", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell_data_view

        let result_data = data_array[indexPath.row]

        t_cell.t_std_name.text = (result_data as AnyObject).value(forKey: "stdName") as? String

        t_cell.t_roll_no.text = (result_data as AnyObject).value(forKey: "stdRoll") as? String

        t_cell.t_std_dept.text = (result_data as AnyObject).value(forKey: "stdDept") as? String

        t_cell.t_grade.text = (result_data as AnyObject).value(forKey: "stdGrade") as? String

        t_cell.t_img_view.image = UIImage(data: (result_data as AnyObject).value(forKey: "stdImage") as! Data)



        return t_cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

    {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "data_passing", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

    {

        if segue.identifier == "data_passing"

        {

            let view_c = segue.destination as! ViewController_Register

            let index_path = table_view.indexPathForSelectedRow





            let update_std_result = self.data_array[(index_path?.row)!]

            view_c.data_result = update_std_result as! NSManagedObject

        }

    }
```

VIEWCONTROLLER--2:

=====================>

```
import UIKit

import CoreData



class ViewController_Register: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate

{

    @IBOutlet var std_name: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var std_roll: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var std_dept: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var std_grade: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var std_image: UIImageView!



    var data_result:NSManagedObject!



    override func viewDidLoad()

    {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        std_image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        if data_result != nil

        {

            std_name.text = data_result.value(forKey: "stdName") as? String

            std_roll.text = data_result.value(forKey: "stdRoll") as? String

            std_dept.text = data_result.value(forKey: "stdDept") as? String

            std_grade.text = data_result.value(forKey: "stdGrade") as? String

            std_image.image = UIImage(data: data_result.value(forKey: "stdImage") as! Data)

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    @IBAction func image_action(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)

    {

        let img_pick = UIImagePickerController()

        img_pick.delegate = self

        img_pick.allowsEditing = true

        img_pick.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(img_pick, animated: true)

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])

    {

        if let img_delegate = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        {

            std_image.image = img_delegate

        }

        else

        {

            print("Error")

        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



    @IBAction func register_action(_ sender: Any)

    {

        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate



        let context_view = app.persistentContainer.viewContext



        if data_result != nil

        {

            data_result.setValue(std_name.text, forKey: "stdName")

            data_result.setValue(std_roll.text, forKey: "stdRoll")

            data_result.setValue(std_dept.text, forKey: "stdDept")

            data_result.setValue(std_grade.text, forKey: "stdGrade")

            let img_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(std_image.image!, 1.0)!

            data_result.setValue(img_data, forKey: "stdImage")

        }

        else

        {



        let student = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Student_detail", into: context_view) as NSManagedObject



        student.setValue(std_name.text, forKey: "stdName")

        student.setValue(std_roll.text, forKey: "stdRoll")

        student.setValue(std_dept.text, forKey: "stdDept")

        student.setValue(std_grade.text, forKey: "stdGrade")

        let img_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(std_image.image!, 1.0)!

        student.setValue(img_data, forKey: "stdImage")

        do

        {

            try context_view.save()

            print("name is-->",std_name.text!,"roll no is-->",std_roll.text!,"dept is -->",std_dept.text!)

        }

        catch let error as NSError

        {

            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }

    }

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)



    }


}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code. ALSO: **pay attention to formatting your post**

Comment: Thanks @pirho . Noted and next time onwards I will follow the same.